# Provider does not refresh the list of a DropDownMenu - Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have a personal API from where I retrieve all the information I need, the connection works fine, but the problem is when I want to show this values, I have a provider where I put all the data I need from the API, and I call it to put those items in the DropDownMenu, but the problem is that the values does not appear, even after the data have arrived, I know this thanks to debugging, here is some code:

this is the code of the widget where I'm calling the provider:

```
Column(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: [
                          Container(
                            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                            height: 10,
                            width: 100,
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                                color: Colors.grey),
                          )
                        ]),
                  ),
                  IconList(
                    labelText: 'Landmarks',
                    icon: Icons.panorama_horizontal_outlined,
                    items: context.watch<Landmarks>().getLandmarksNameList(), //Here is my provider
                  ),
                  const IconInput(
                      labelText: '1', icon: Icons.addchart_outlined),
                  const IconInput(
                      labelText: '1', icon: Icons.addchart_outlined),
                  ListView.builder(
                    physics: const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemCount: 2,
                    itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                      return UserCard(user: usersList[index]);
                    },
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

this is the widget iconList, where I have the dropDownMenu:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class IconList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final IconData icon;
  final List<String> items = [];

  IconList({super.key, required this.labelText, required this.icon, items});

  @override
  State<IconList> createState() => _IconListState();
}

class _IconListState extends State<IconList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String selectedItem = '';
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedItem = widget.items.first;
    }
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(widget.icon),
          DropdownButton<String>(
            value: selectedItem,
            items: widget.items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my provider:

```
class Landmarks with ChangeNotifier {
  final List<Landmark> _items = [];

  List<Landmark> get landmarks => _items;

  void addLandmarks(List<Landmark> value) {
    _items.addAll(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  List<String> getLandmarksNameList() {
    List<String> list = [];
    print(_items.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < _items.length; i++) {
      list.add(_items[i].name);
    }
    return list;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems with you code:

##### Problem 1

In your `IconList` constructor

```dart
IconList({super.key, required this.labelText, required this.icon, items});
```

you are accessing `items`, but really you should access `this.items`.

To do so, you also shouldn't initialize items with:

```
  final List<String> items = [];
```

Your code should look like this:

```dart
class IconList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final IconData icon;
  final List<String> items;

  IconList(
      {super.key,
      required this.labelText,
      required this.icon,
      required this.items});
```

##### Problem 2

Within your `build` method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    String selectedItem = '';
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedItem = widget.items.first;
    }
```

you are initializing `selectedItem`, which means that every `setState`, `selectedItem` will get reset to its *original* value since it's *within* the `build` method. Instead, move `selectedItem` to outside the `build`, to your `_state` class:

```dart
class _IconListState extends State<IconList> {
  String selectedItem = ''; //<-- Initialize it here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedItem = widget.items.first;
    }
    return Container(
```

Your `IconList` should look like this:

```dart
class IconList extends StatefulWidget {
  final String labelText;
  final IconData icon;
  final List<String> items;

  IconList(
      {super.key,
      required this.labelText,
      required this.icon,
      required this.items});

  @override
  State<IconList> createState() => _IconListState();
}

class _IconListState extends State<IconList> {
  String selectedItem = ''; //<-- Initialize it here
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    if (widget.items.isNotEmpty) {
      selectedItem = widget.items.first;
    }
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
      child: Row(
        children: [
          Icon(widget.icon),
          DropdownButton<String>(
            value: selectedItem,
            items: widget.items.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
              print("item is $value");
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                value: value,
                child: Text(value),
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (String? value) {
              setState(() {
                selectedItem = value!;
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```